# if i type in textbox 1,3 then checkbox1 and checkbox3 will be disabled not checked !

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

if i type in textbox 1,3 then checkbox1 and checkbox3 will be disabled not checked !!

The coding i provide below is working but ,...it chekec the cjeckoxes according to the text in textbox i.e (1,3) then checkbox1 and checkbox3 will be checked ..

.. but i want when i type 1,3 in textbox then checkbox1 and checkbox3 will be disabled and remain unchecked .........

can any body update my this code to perform above operation ?

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim separator As Char = ","
    Dim allIIDs As New List(Of Int32)
    If TextBox1.Text.Length <> 0 Then
        For Each strNum As String In TextBox1.Text.Split(separator)<br>
            Dim num As Int32
            If Int32.TryParse(strNum, num) Then
                allIIDs.Add(num)

            End If
        Next
    End If
    allIIDs.Sort()
    For Each control As Control In Panel1.Controls
        If TypeOf control Is CheckBox Then
            Dim chk As CheckBox = DirectCast(control, CheckBox)
            chk.Enabled = False = allIIDs.BinarySearch(Int32.Parse(chk.Text)) > -1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: **exact** duplicate of [when i type 1,2 then checkbox1 and checkbox2 will disabled and unchecked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176772/when-i-type-1-2-then-checkbox1-and-checkbox2-will-disabled-and-unchecked)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want those checkboxes disabled that are comma separated listed  in the TextBox **and** the other checkboxes enabled. (improved a little bit your code, because [originally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173949/i-have-4-checkboxes-and-1-textbox-in-webform-if-i-type-in-textbox-1-2-then-checkb/4174390#4174390) it came from me)

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim separator As Char = ","c
    Dim allIIDs As New List(Of String)
    If TextBox1.Text.Length <> 0 Then
        For Each strNum As String In TextBox1.Text.Split(separator)
            Dim num As Int32
            If Int32.TryParse(strNum, num) Then
                allIIDs.Add(strNum)
            End If
        Next
    End If
    allIIDs.Sort()
    For Each control As Control In Panel1.Controls
        If TypeOf control Is CheckBox Then
            Dim chk As CheckBox = DirectCast(control, CheckBox)
            chk.Enabled = allIIDs.BinarySearch(chk.Text) < 0
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Remember to set `AutoPostBack="false"` to TextBox1, otherwise you need 2 Postbacks to see the disabled state of the checkboxes.

Comment: Hey tim, but ... when i type ...1,2 in textbox then checkbox1 and checkbox2 will be disabled and after that when i type 3,4 in textbox then 1,2 is enabled and checkbox3 and checkbox4 will be disabled..

Comment: Yes, isn't it exactly what you wanted?