# How to disable checkboxes according to textbox text !

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [if i type in textbox 1,3 then checkbox1 and checkbox3 will be disabled not checked !!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178902/if-i-type-in-textbox-1-3-then-checkbox1-and-checkbox3-will-be-disabled-not-checke)

i want to disable checkboxes according to textbox text

For example --- if i enter 1,4 in textbox then checkbox1 and checkbox4 will be disabled and even after that when i type 2,3 in textbox then checkbox2 and checkbox3 will be disabled and checkbox1 and checkbox4 will be enabled again ...

Remember : i wanna use this coding with unlimited no. of checkboxes...

How to do this ?

The code mentioned below can checked according to textbox text --but i want to disabled ony not checked ....

Protected Sub TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyTextBox.TextChanged
    Dim separator As Char = ","c
    Dim allIIDs As New List(Of String)
    If MyTextBox.Text.Length <> 0 Then
        For Each strNum As String In MyTextBox.Text.Split(separator)
            Dim num As Int32
            If Int32.TryParse(strNum, num) Then
                allIIDs.Add(strNum)
            End If
        Next
    End If
    allIIDs.Sort()
    For Each control As Control In UpdatePanel1.Controls
        If TypeOf control Is CheckBox Then
            Dim chk As CheckBox = DirectCast(control, CheckBox)
            chk.Checked = allIIDs.BinarySearch(chk.Text) > -1
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Comment: Duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173949/i-have-4-checkboxes-and-1-textbox-in-webform-if-i-type-in-textbox-1-2-then-checkb

Comment: ho no, not again, just reuse what you have with the checked from your previous questions

Comment: How many times are you going to ask the exact same question in a 24 hour span?  Already asked it 4 times and received two answers (under this account).

Comment: and same question under others accounts

Comment: But, no one are able to answer this question .... thats why i reupdate my question ...

Comment: update one of your other question with what is not working, don't create new question

Answer (score 0):

Let's see...

```
var boxesToDisable = textbox.value.split(","), i;
for( i=0; i<checkboxCount; i++) {
    document.getElementById('checkbox'+i).disabled = false;
}
for( i=0; i<boxesToDisable.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('checkbos'+i).disabled = true;
}
```

HTH

Comment: How to use this...code in ASP.NET (VB)